# ReactJs - Returning a string and tag html in a one object

Tags: reactjs

```
if (this.state.typeModal == 'isRemoveRoute') {
    return <Quest 
                question={'Deseja excluir a rota do produto?  '+ this.state.objModal.product.sku +' - '+ this.state.objModal.product.name}
                handleModal={this.handleModal}
                action={() => this.removeRoute(this.state.objModal.product, this.state.objModal.session)}
            />;
}
```

After message `deseja excluir a rota do produto?` I need to return the tag html '< br/ >' for a line break.

Comment: try to make a () inside of {}

Comment: question={'Deseja excluir a rota do produto?  '+(<br/>)+  this returning Object object

Comment: I thought about question={('Deseja excluir a rota do produto?'+<br/>+ ...

Comment: I have tried this but it continues to return object object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases where you are going to be using html within a string it is much better to instead just have `question` return jsx

```
const question = (
 <div> Deseja excluir a rota do produto? <br/> { this.state.objModal.product.sku} - { this.state.objModal.product.name }</div>
)

return ( 
  <Quest 
    question={question}
    handleModal={this.handleModal}
    action={() => this.removeRoute(this.state.objModal.product, 
      this.state.objModal.session)}
  />;
)
```

otherwise you are going to have to do `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to parse the html that is within the string. Leveraging jsx is much nicer and imo cleaner.

Then in your quest component you just put `this.props.question` wherever its needed and it will render the jsx

Comment: Thanks ma friend , this was a sucessful reply :)